# Show that if $f: R^n\rightarrow R$ is differentiable at $x_0$ then $1/f$ is also differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f:A\subset  R^n\rightarrow R $  be a scalar function with A open and differentiable at $\bar x_0\in A$. I need to prove that $1/f$ is also differentiable at $\bar x_0$ (if f(**x**)$\neq$ $0$ $\forall x$$\in$ A) and that:
 D($\frac{1}{f}$)($\bar x_0$)=$\frac{-Df(\bar x_0)}{f^2(\bar x_0)}$.
I believe that to prove it I need to prove the following limit:
$\lim_{\bar x \to \bar x_0} \frac{\frac{1}{f(\bar x)}-\frac{1}{f(\bar x_0)}-(\frac{-Df(\bar x_0)}{f^2(\bar x_0)})(\bar x-\bar x_0)}{\Vert \bar x-\bar x_0\Vert} =0$
  To that end I'm trying to make it similar to the limit:
$\lim_{\bar x \to \bar x_0} \frac{f(\bar x)-f(\bar x_0)-Df(\bar x_0)(\bar x-\bar x_0)}{\Vert \bar x-\bar x_0\Vert} =0$
which I know equals zero because that is the definition of differentiability I was given.
This is what I've got so far:
$\lim_{\bar x\to \bar x_0} \frac{-1}{f^2(\bar x_0)f(\bar x)}\frac{f(\bar x)f(\bar x_0)-f^2(\bar x_0)-f(\bar x)Df(\bar x_0)(\bar x- \bar x_0)}{\Vert \bar x -\bar x_0 \Vert}=\lim_{\bar x\to \bar x_0} \frac{-1}{f(\bar x_0)f(\bar x)}\frac{f(\bar x)-f(\bar x_0)-\frac{f(\bar x)}{f(\bar x_0) }Df(\bar x_0)(\bar x- \bar x_0)}{\Vert \bar x -\bar x_0 \Vert}$
My question is if this would the right way to try to prove the assignment and how could one continue if that is the case.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, then $$f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+\nabla f(x_0)\cdot h+o(|h|).$$
Now, using the fact that $$\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+o(x),$$
you get

$$\frac{1}{f(x_0+h)}=\frac{1}{f(x_0)+\nabla f(x_0)\cdot h+o(|h|)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{f(x_0)}-\frac{\nabla f(x_0)}{f(x_0)^2}\cdot h+o(|h|),$$
and thus, the claim follow.

Comment: But why is the last statement enough to prove the claim?

Comment: What is the definition of being differentiable ? @Moller